# how to divide rdd data into two in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a data in Spark RDD and I want to divide it into two part with a scale such as 0.7. For example if the RDD looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to divide it into `rdd1`:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and `rdd2`:

```
[8,9,10]
```

with the scale 0.7. The `rdd1` and `rdd2` should be random every time. I tried this way:

```
seed = random.randint(0,10000)
rdd1 = data.sample(False,scale,seed)
rdd2 = data.subtract(rdd1)
```

and it works sometimes but when my data contains `dict` I experienced some problems. For example with data as follows:

```
[{1:2},{3:1},{5:4,2;6}]
```

I get

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 6):

Both `RDDs`

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10))
test, train = rdd.randomSplit(weights=[0.3, 0.7], seed=1)

test.collect()
## [4, 7, 8]

train.collect()
## [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

and `DataFrames`

```
df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["x"])

test, train = df.randomSplit(weights=[0.3, 0.7])
```

provide `randomSplit` method which can be used here.

**Notes**:

- `randomSplit` is expressed using a single `filter` for each output `RDD`. In general it is not possible to yield multiple `RDDs` from a single Spark transformation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971246/1560062 for details.
- You cannot use `subtract` with dictionaries because internally it is expressed `cogorup` and because of that requires objects to be `hashable`. See also [A list as a key for PySpark's reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31404238/1560062)