# A list as a key for PySpark's reduceByKey

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd, pyspark

I am attempting to call the reduceByKey function of pyspark on data of the format `(([a,b,c], 1), ([a,b,c], 1), ([a,d,b,e], 1), ...`

It seems pyspark will not accept an array as the key in normal key, value reduction by simply applying .reduceByKey(add).

I have already tried first converting the array to a string, by `.map((x,y): (str(x),y))` but this does not work because post processing of the strings back into arrays is too slow.

Is there a way I can make pyspark use the array as a key or use another function to quickly convert the strings back to arrays?

here is the associated error code

```
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 268, in mergeValues
    d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
    enter code here
```

**SUMMARY**:

input:`x =[([a,b,c], 1), ([a,b,c], 1), ([a,d,b,e], 1),  ...]`

desired output :`y =[([a,b,c], 2), ([a,d,b,e], 1),...]`
such that I could access `a` by `y[0][0][0]` and `2` by `y[0][1]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (tuple(k), v)).groupByKey()
```

Since Python lists are mutable it means that cannot be hashed (don't provide `__hash__` method):

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a_list.__hash__ is None
True
>>> hash(a_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Tuples from the other hand are immutable and provide `__hash__` method implementation:

```
>>> a_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a_tuple.__hash__ is None
False
>>> hash(a_tuple)
2528502973977326415
```

hence can be used as a key. Similarly if you want to use unique values as a key you should use `frozenset`:

```
rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (frozenset(k), v)).groupByKey().collect()
```

instead of `set`.

```
# This will fail with TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (set(k), v)).groupByKey().collect()
```

Comment: thanks that really helps a lot with my understanding of spark in general

Comment: You're welcome. BTW It is not Spark specific in particular. Same thing applies when you use plain Python `dicts` or `sets`.