# How does HashPartitioner work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

I read up on the documentation of [`HashPartitioner`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html). Unfortunately nothing much was explained except for the API calls. I am under the assumption that `HashPartitioner` partitions the distributed set based on the hash of the keys. For example if my data is like

```
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3)
```

So partitioner would put this into different partitions with same keys falling in the same partition. However I do not understand the significance of the constructor argument

```
new HashPartitoner(numPartitions) //What does numPartitions do?
```

For the above dataset how would the results differ if I did

```
new HashPartitoner(1)
new HashPartitoner(2)
new HashPartitoner(10)
```

So how does `HashPartitioner` work actually?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Well, lets make your dataset marginally more interesting:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(for {
    x <- 1 to 3
    y <- 1 to 2
} yield (x, None), 8)
```

We have six elements:

```scala
rdd.count
```

```
Long = 6
```

no partitioner:

```scala
rdd.partitioner
```

```
Option[org.apache.spark.Partitioner] = None
```

and eight partitions:

```scala
rdd.partitions.length
```

```
Int = 8
```

Now lets define small helper to count number of elements per partition:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

def countByPartition(rdd: RDD[(Int, None.type)]) = {
    rdd.mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(iter.length))
}
```

Since we don't have partitioner our dataset is distributed uniformly between partitions ([Default Partitioning Scheme in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34491219/1560062)):

```scala
countByPartition(rdd).collect()
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

[image: inital-distribution]

Now lets repartition our dataset:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
val rddOneP = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(1))
```

Since parameter passed to `HashPartitioner` defines number of partitions we have expect one partition:

```scala
rddOneP.partitions.length
```

```
Int = 1
```

Since we have only one partition it contains all elements:

```scala
countByPartition(rddOneP).collect
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(6)
```

[image: hash-partitioner-1]

Note that the order of values after the shuffle is non-deterministic.

Same way if we use `HashPartitioner(2)`

```scala
val rddTwoP = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))
```

we'll get 2 partitions:

```scala
rddTwoP.partitions.length
```

```
Int = 2
```

Since `rdd` is partitioned by key data won't be distributed uniformly anymore:

```scala
countByPartition(rddTwoP).collect()
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(2, 4)
```

Because with have three keys and only two different values of `hashCode` mod `numPartitions` there is nothing unexpected here:

```scala
(1 to 3).map((k: Int) => (k, k.hashCode, k.hashCode % 2))
```

```
scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int, Int)] = Vector((1,1,1), (2,2,0), (3,3,1))
```

Just to confirm the above:

```scala
rddTwoP.mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(iter.map(_._1).toSet)).collect()
```

```
Array[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Array(Set(2), Set(1, 3))
```

[image: hash-partitioner-2]

Finally with `HashPartitioner(7)` we get seven partitions, three non-empty with 2 elements each:

```scala
val rddSevenP = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(7))
rddSevenP.partitions.length
```

```
Int = 7
```

```scala
countByPartition(rddTenP).collect()
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0)
```

[image: hash-partitioner-7]

#### Summary and Notes

- `HashPartitioner` takes a single argument which defines number of partitions
- values are assigned to partitions using `hash` of keys. `hash` function may differ depending on the language (Scala RDD may use `hashCode`, `DataSets` use MurmurHash 3, PySpark, [`portable_hash`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/330c3e33bd10f035f49cf3d13357eb2d6d90dabc/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L59-L87)).

  In simple case like this, where key is a small integer, you can assume that `hash` is an identity (`i = hash(i)`).

  Scala API uses [`nonNegativeMod`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4e27578faa67c7a71a9b938aafbaf79bdbf36831/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L1663-L1666) to determine partition based on computed hash,
- if distribution of keys is not uniform you can end up in situations when part of your cluster is idle
- keys have to be hashable. You can check my answer for [A list as a key for PySpark's reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404405/1560062) to read about PySpark specific issues. Another possible problem is highlighted by [HashPartitioner documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner):

  > Java arrays have hashCodes that are based on the arrays' identities rather than their contents, so attempting to partition an RDD[Array[*]] or RDD[(Array[*], _)] using a HashPartitioner will produce an unexpected or incorrect result.
- In Python 3 you have to make sure that hashing is consistent. See [What does Exception: Randomness of hash of string should be disabled via PYTHONHASHSEED mean in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36798833/1560062)
- Hash partitioner is neither injective nor surjective. Multiple keys can be assigned to a single partition and some partitions can remain empty.
- Please note that currently hash based methods don't work in Scala when combined with REPL defined case classes ([Case class equality in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301998/1560062)).
- `HashPartitioner` (or any other `Partitioner`) shuffles the data. Unless partitioning is reused between multiple operations it doesn't reduce amount of data to be shuffled.

Comment: Excellent write up, thank you. However, I noticed in the images that you have `(1, None)` with `hash(2) % P` where P is partition. Shouldn't it be `hash(1) % P` ?

Comment: Im using spark 2.2, and there is no `partitionBy` api in rdd. there is a partitionBy under dataframe.write, but it does not take Partitioner as argument.

Comment: awsome reply... shuffle is based on partioner, a good partioner may reduce the shuffled data amount.

Comment: Great  answer. I have a question which I'm not getting a solid answer in the internet. When we use df.repartition(n) I.e when we don't specify any column as a key, then how the hash function workers internally as there's nothing to be hashed on?

Comment: @dsk, if you don't specify a key, I believe repartition uses RoundRobinPartitioning.  Some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123887/how-does-round-robin-partitioning-in-spark-work).

Answer (score 8):

`RDD` is distributed this means it is split on some number of parts. Each of this partitions is potentially on different machine. Hash partitioner with argument `numPartitions` chooses on what partition to place pair `(key, value)` in following way:

1. Creates exactly `numPartitions` partitions.
2. Places `(key, value)` in partition with number `Hash(key) % numPartitions`

Answer (score 3):

The `HashPartitioner.getPartition` method takes a *key* as its argument and returns the *index* of the partition which the key belongs to. The partitioner has to know what the valid indices are, so it returns numbers in the right range. The number of partitions is specified through the `numPartitions` constructor argument.

The implementation returns roughly `key.hashCode() % numPartitions`. See [Partitioner.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L78) for more details.