# Case class equality in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching, rdd, case-class

Why does pattern matching in Spark not work the same as in Scala?  See example below...  function `f()` tries to pattern match on class, which works in the Scala REPL but fails in Spark and results in all "???".  `f2()` is a workaround that gets the desired result in Spark using `.isInstanceOf()`, but I understand that to be bad form in Scala.

Any help on pattern matching the correct way in this scenario in Spark would be greatly appreciated.

```
abstract class a extends Serializable {val a: Int}
case class b(a: Int) extends a 
case class bNull(a: Int=0) extends a 

val x: List[a] = List(b(0), b(1), bNull())
val xRdd = sc.parallelize(x)
```

attempt at pattern matching which works in Scala REPL but fails in Spark

```
def f(x: a) = x match {
    case b(n) => "b"
    case bNull(n) => "bnull"
    case _ => "???"
}
```

workaround that functions in Spark, but is bad form (I think)

```
def f2(x: a) = {
    if (x.isInstanceOf[b]) {
        "b"
    } else if (x.isInstanceOf[bNull]) {
        "bnull"
    } else {
        "???"
    }
}
```

View results

```
xRdd.map(f).collect                   //does not work in Spark
                                      // result: Array("???", "???", "???")
xRdd.map(f2).collect                  // works in Spark
                                      // resut: Array("b", "b", "bnull")
x.map(f(_))                           // works in Scala REPL    
                                      // result: List("b", "b", "bnull")
```

Versions used...
Spark results run in spark-shell (Spark 1.6 on AWS EMR-4.3)
Scala REPL in SBT 0.13.9 (Scala 2.10.5)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known issue with Spark REPL. You can find more details in [SPARK-2620](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620). It affects multiple operations in Spark REPL including most of transformations on the `PairwiseRDDs`. For example:

```
case class Foo(x: Int)

val foos = Seq(Foo(1), Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(2))
foos.distinct.size
// Int = 2

val foosRdd = sc.parallelize(foos, 4)
foosRdd.distinct.count
// Long = 4  

foosRdd.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect
// Array[(Foo, Int)] = Array((Foo(1),1), (Foo(1),1), (Foo(2),1), (Foo(2),1))

foosRdd.first == foos.head
// Boolean = false

Foo.unapply(foosRdd.first) == Foo.unapply(foos.head)
// Boolean = true
```

What makes it even worse is that the results depend on the data distribution:

```
sc.parallelize(foos, 1).distinct.count
// Long = 2

sc.parallelize(foos, 1).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect
// Array[(Foo, Int)] = Array((Foo(2),2), (Foo(1),2))
```

The simplest thing you can do is to define and package required case classes outside REPL. Any code submitted directly using `spark-submit` should work as well.

In Scala 2.11+ you can create a package directly in the REPL with `paste -raw`.

```
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package bar

case class Bar(x: Int)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> import bar.Bar
import bar.Bar

scala> sc.parallelize(Seq(Bar(1), Bar(1), Bar(2), Bar(2))).distinct.collect
res1: Array[bar.Bar] = Array(Bar(1), Bar(2))
```

Comment: Thanks zero323!  I see mention of pattern matching not working in the spark shell there, but no details...  you're saying if I define my case classes in a jar, I'll be able to pattern match on them in the REPL?  Thanks again!

Comment: Exactly. Define outside, build jar, include in the `CLASSPATH` and import.