# Equals function doesn't work with custom object in spark

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, spark-repl

I'm haveing trouble, I presume with serialization, in a Spark repl.

I have the following code snippet:

```
class Foobar (val a: Int, val b: Int) extends Serializable {
  override def equals (other: Any): Boolean =
    other match {
      case that: Foobar =>
        println("Comparison of similar objects")
        this.a == that.a && this.b == that.b
      case _ =>
        println("Comparison of disparate objects")
        false
    }
  override def toString = s"[$a:$b]"
}
```

If I create two instances, one (foo) on a worker, and one (bar) on the driver:

```
val foo = sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).map(n => new Foobar(n, n)).collect.apply(0)
val bar = new Foobar(1, 1)
```

then `foo != bar` (and spouts "Comparison of disparate objects") - yet

- `foo.getClass == bar.getClass`
- `foo.a == bar.a`, and
- `foo.b == bar.b`

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: The same thing happens if I use a case class

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/35301998/1560062 and related JIRA ticket.