# How to set PYTHONHASHSEED on AWS EMR

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

Is there any way to set an environment variable on all nodes of an EMR cluster?

I am getting an error when trying to use reduceByKey() in Python3 PySpark, and getting an error regarding the hash seed. I can see this is a known error, and that the environment varialbe PYTHONHASHSEED needs to be set to the same value on all nodes of the cluster, but I haven't had any luck with it.

I have tried adding a variable to spark-env through the cluster configuration:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-env",

      "Configurations": [
      {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3",
          "PYTHONHASHSEED": "123"
       }
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "Classification": "spark",
   "Properties": {
     "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

but this doesn't work. I have also tried adding a bootstrap script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONHASHSEED=123
```

but this also doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the `/usr/bin/python3` isn't picking up the environment variable `PYTHONHASHSEED` that you are defining in the cluster configuration under the `spark-env` scope.

You ought using `python34` instead of `/usr/bin/python3` and set the configuration as followed :

```
[
   {
      "classification":"spark-defaults",
      "properties":{
         // [...]
      }
   },
   {
      "configurations":[
         {
            "classification":"export",
            "properties":{
               "PYSPARK_PYTHON":"python34",
               "PYTHONHASHSEED":"123"
            }
         }
      ],
      "classification":"spark-env",
      "properties":{
        // [...]
      }
   }
]
```

Now, let's test it. I define a bash script call both `python`s :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "using python34"
for i in `seq 1 10`;
  do
    python -c "print(hash('foo'))";
  done
echo "----------------------"
echo "using /usr/bin/python3"
for i in `seq 1 10`;
  do
    /usr/bin/python3 -c "print(hash('foo'))";
  done
```

The verdict :

```
[hadoop@ip-10-0-2-182 ~]$ bash test.sh
using python34
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
-4177197833195190597
----------------------
using /usr/bin/python3
8867846273747294950
-7610044127871105351
6756286456855631480
-4541503224938367706
7326699722121877093
3336202789104553110
3462714165845110404
-5390125375246848302
-7753272571662122146
8018968546238984314
```

**PS1:** I am using AMI release `emr-4.8.2`.

**PS2:** Snippet inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799130/3415409).

**EDIT:** I have tested the following using `pyspark`.

```
16/11/22 07:16:56 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1479798580078_0001
16/11/22 07:16:56 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.4.3 (default, Sep  1 2016 23:33:38)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> print(hash('foo'))
-2457967226571033580
>>> print(hash('foo'))
-2457967226571033580
>>> print(hash('foo'))
-2457967226571033580
>>> print(hash('foo'))
-2457967226571033580
>>> print(hash('foo'))
-2457967226571033580
```

Also created a simple application (`simple_app.py`):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName = "simple-app")

numbers = [hash('foo') for i in range(10)]

print(numbers)
```

Which also seems to work perfectly :

```
[hadoop@ip-*** ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn simple_app.py
```

Output (truncated) :

```
[...]
16/11/22 07:28:42 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
[-5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594] // THE RELEVANT LINE IS HERE.
16/11/22 07:28:42 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
[...]
```

As you can see it also works returning the same hash each time.

**EDIT 2:** From the comments, it seems like you are trying to compute hashes on the executors and not the driver, thus you'll need to set up `spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED`, inside your spark application configuration so it can be propagated on the executors (it's one way to do it).

> Note : Setting the environment variables for executors is the same with YARN client, use the `spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName].`

Thus the following minimalist example with `simple_app.py` :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().set("spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED","123")
sc = SparkContext(appName="simple-app", conf=conf)

numbers = sc.parallelize(['foo']*10).map(lambda x: hash(x)).collect()

print(numbers)
```

And now let's test it again. Here is the truncated output :

```
16/11/22 14:14:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at /home/hadoop/simple_app.py:6, took 14.251514 s
[-5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594, -5869373620241885594]
16/11/22 14:14:34 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

I think that this covers all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. There is a problem with your script, the config only sets the spark python version to be python34, the default shell "python" still points to Python2.x. If you replace python with /usr/bin/python34 you'll see different hash values each time.

Comment: Your example still only runs on the driver node in one Python instance. If you make a parallel collection and run it through spark-submit you will see different hash values (or at least I do for a 3 node cluster). If you replace the "numbers=..." line with: numbers = sc.parallelize(['foo']*10).map(lambda x: hash(x)).collect()

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

From the spark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables)

> Note: When running Spark on YARN in cluster mode, environment variables need to be set using the spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName] property in your conf/spark-defaults.conf file. **Environment variables that are set in spark-env.sh will not be reflected in the YARN Application Master process in cluster mode.** See the YARN-related Spark Properties for more information.

Properties are listed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties) so I think you want this:

> Add the environment variable specified by EnvironmentVariableName to the Application Master process launched on YARN.

```
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED="XXXX"
```

EMR docs for configuring spark-defaults.conf are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html#spark-change-defaults).

```
[
    {
      "Classification": "spark-defaults",
      "Properties": {
        "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED: "XXX"
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: This looks like it might be what I need, but I can't see where I add this config in EMR?

Comment: Added an EMR config snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered the same problem, adding the following configuration solved it:

```
# Some settings...
Configurations=[
        {
            "Classification": "spark-env",
            "Properties": {},
            "Configurations": [
                {
                    "Classification": "export",
                    "Properties": {
                        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "python34"
                    },
                    "Configurations": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Classification": "hadoop-env",
            "Properties": {},
            "Configurations": [
                {
                    "Classification": "export",
                    "Properties": {
                        "PYTHONHASHSEED": "0"
                    },
                    "Configurations": []
                }
            ]
        }
        ],
# Some more settings...
```

Be careful: we do not use yarn as a cluster manager, for the moment the cluster is only running Hadoop and Spark.

**EDIT** : Following Tim B comment, this seems to work also with yarn installed as a cluster manager.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Even on the default EMR image running yarn.

Comment: Good to know @TimB ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it via the bootstrap script but you'll need to do something like this:

```
echo "PYTHONHASHSEED=XXXX" >> /home/hadoop/.bashrc
```

(or possibly `.profile`)

So that it's picked up by the spark processes when they are launched.

Your configuration looks reasonable though, it might be worth setting it in the `hadoop-env` section instead?

Comment: I don't think this will set PYTHONHASHSEED on the worker nodes, which is the issue?