# spark cluster on aws emr cant find spark-env.sh

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cluster-computing, amazon-emr

I am playing with apache-spark on aws emr, and trying to use [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/) to set the cluster to use python3,

I use the command as the last command in a bootstrap script

```
sudo sed -i -e '$a\export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3' /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
```

When I use it the cluster crashes during the bootstrap with the following error.

> sed: can't read /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh: No such file or
>   directory

How should I set it to use python3 properly?

This is not a duplicate [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677713/how-to-set-pythonhashseed-on-aws-emr), My issue is that the cluster is not finding the spark-env.sh file while bootstrapping, while the other question addresses the issue of the system not finding python3

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @MehdiB. will post an answer about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I did not use that script, but Used the [EMR configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html) file that is available on the creation stage, It gave me the proper configurations via spark_submit (in the aws gui) If you need it to be available for pyspark scripts in a more programatic way, you can use os.environ to set the pyspark python version in the python script