# Should I reuse a HashPartitioner on two different RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In all examples, I always see partitionBy receiving a *new* instance of a HashPartitioner

> `val rddTenP = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))`

I am joining two RDDs. They have key column that has values from the same set `userId`. Should I partition both of them for the join to be more efficient? If yes, should I create one HashPartitioner instance hp

> `val hp: HashPartitioner = new spark.HashPartitioner(84)`
>   and pass hp to both partitionBy methods, so as to have the rows to be joined fall to the same node? Is that the way partitionBy works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way using the same partitioner to optimize your joins (by avoiding shuffles). You *can* use the same instance of hash partitioner since it is immutable. But if you use 2 instances of hash partitioner with the same number of partitions parameter (roughly, partitionIndex = key.hasCode mod numOfPartitions), it works too because they are equal:

```
 override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case h: HashPartitioner =>
      h.numPartitions == numPartitions
    case _ =>
      false
  }
```

For details and detailed explanations how it works, see:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala
And
[How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/apache-spark-hashpartitioner-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy. In Summary, using `new HashPartitioner(10)` in each partitionBy actually creates the same HashPartitioner and so would create same partitions for same keys...