# How determine that which partition a key to go to in sort shuffle of Spark

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

In the sort % spill process, which key is the start of a partition and anther?

Comment: Is this Spark Core or SQL? Can you show the exact code snippet you think about to make sure we're talking about the same things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work)

Comment: It is Spark Core. As the [figure](https://0x0fff.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/spark_hash_shuffle_with_consolidation.png) shown. Thanks. @Jacek Laskowski

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether it's Spark Core (with RDDs) or Spark SQL (with Datasets), the default partitioner is [HashPartitioner](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner) where the hash of a key gives the partition:

> A org.apache.spark.Partitioner that implements hash-based partitioning using Java's Object.hashCode.

Comment: I beg to disagree :)

Comment: Let's have this conversation after I got all the needed info from the OP :) If it's Spark SQL that answer might get tricker (and won't be a duplicate).

Comment: Well, details aside, docs you quote are irrelevant / incorrect for `Datasets`.