# Pyspark dataframe repartitioning puts all data in one partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with schema as follows:

```
root
 |-- category_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- article_title: string (nullable = true)
```

And data that looks likes this:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|category_id|     articletitle   |
+-----------+--------------------+
|       1000|HP EliteOne 800 G...|
|       1000|ASUS  EB1501P ATM...|
|       1000|HP EliteOne 800 G...|
|          1|ASUS R557LA-XO119...|
|          1|HP EliteOne 800 G...|
+-----------+--------------------+
```

There are just two distinct `category_id` 1000 and 1.

I want to do a repartition by `category_id` and `mapPartition` on each of the partitions.

```
p_df = df.repartition(2, "category_id")
p_df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(some_func)
```

But data is not getting partitioned correctly, the expected result is that each mappartition will have data only for one `category_id`. But actual result is that one partition gets 0 records while the other gets all the records.

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work) on how spark partitioner works. My question is different as the answers contain only explanation on how the partitioner works, but my question is about why this happens (which is answered already) and how to fix it.

Comment: How did you arrive to the conclusion that one partition is empty and the other one has all the records? Can you add the output of `p_df.withColumn("partition" , spark_partition_id()).show()` ?

Comment: It's alright. It gives accurate partitioning for Spark 1.6 but gives the same partition id for all records in Spark 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason on why repartition is putting all data in one partition is explained by @Ramesh Maharjan in the above answer. More on hash partitioning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I was able to make data go to different partitioner by using a custom partitioner. I made the rdd into a pairRdd format the (category_id, row) and used the partitionBy method giving in the number of partitions and custom_partitioner.

```
    categories = input_df.select("category_id").distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r.category_id).collect()
    cat_idx = dict([(cat, idx) for idx, cat in enumerate(categories)])

    def category_partitioner(cid):
        return cat_idx[cid]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used the `repartition` and `mapPartitionsWithIndex` functions correctly.

If you apply `explain` function as

```
df.repartition(2, "category_id").explain()
```

you will see the following output which clearly says that its repartitioned into two partitions.

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(category_id#0L, 2)
+- Scan ExistingRDD[category_id#0L,articletitle#1L]
```

**Now the real culprit is the hashPartitioning which treats 1, 10, 1000, 100000 ... as the same hashes as the partition number is *2***

The solution would be to change the partitioning number to 3 or more,

or

change the `category_id` 1000 to something else.