# How to map many to many in spark, based on value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For input dataframe:

```
+-------+-----+-------+------+--------------+-------+----+
|Closing| Flow|Opening|Period|        RowKey|RowKey2|Year|
+-------+-----+-------+------+--------------+-------+----+
|  -2.11|-2.11|    0.0|    01|2016-01-1200-A| 1200-A|2016|
|  -1.11|-1.11|    0.0|    01|2016-01-1200-B| 1200-B|2016|
|   -1.0| -1.0|    0.0|    04|  2016-04-2200|   2200|2016|
|   -1.0| -1.0|    0.0|    04|  2016-04-3000|   3000|2016|
|   -1.0| -1.0|    0.0|    05|2016-05-1200-C| 1200-C|2016|
|    0.0|  1.0|   -1.0|    05|  2016-05-3000|   3000|2016|
|    0.0|  1.0|   -1.0|    08|  2016-08-2200|   2200|2016|
|    1.0|  1.0|    0.0|    09|  2016-09-2200|   2200|2016|
|   -2.0| -1.0|   -1.0|    12|2016-12-1200-C| 1200-C|2016|
|  100.0|100.0|    0.0|    12|  2016-12-4000|   4000|2016|
+-------+-----+-------+------+--------------+-------+----+
```

I would like to apply function from below (where period is list of distinct period values in input["Period] column):

```
def insertPeriod(row, period):
    row = row.asDict()
    row["Period"]=period
    return Row(**row)

def filterOutFromPartion(aggdata, periods):
    output = []
    for period in periods:
        iterator = (item for item in aggdata if item["Period"] == period)
        try:
            found = next(iterator)
            output.append(insertPeriod(found,period))
        except StopIteration:
            if (len(output)==0):
                continue
            else:
                temp = output[-1]
                output.append(insertPeriod(temp,period))
    return iter(output)
```

So that result would be:

```
+--------------+----+------+-------------+-----+--------------+--------------+
|        RowKey|Year|Period|AccountNumber| Flow|OpeningBalance|ClosingBalance|
+--------------+----+------+-------------+-----+--------------+--------------+
|2016-01-1200-A|2016|     1|         1200|-2.11|             0|         -2.11|
|2016-01-1200-B|2016|     1|         1200|-1.11|             0|         -1.11|
|2016-02-1200-A|2016|     2|         1200|    0|         -2.11|         -2.11|
|2016-02-1200-B|2016|     2|         1200|    0|         -1.11|         -1.11|
|2016-03-1200-A|2016|     3|         1200|    0|         -2.11|         -2.11|
|2016-03-1200-B|2016|     3|         1200|    0|         -1.11|         -1.11|
|2016-04-1200-A|2016|     4|         1200|    0|         -2.11|         -2.11|
|2016-04-1200-B|2016|     4|         1200|    0|         -1.11|         -1.11|
| 2016-04-2200-|2016|     4|         2200|   -1|             0|            -1|
| 2016-04-3000-|2016|     4|         3000|   -1|             0|            -1|
|2016-05-1200-A|2016|     5|         1200|    0|         -2.11|         -2.11|
|2016-05-1200-B|2016|     5|         1200|    0|         -1.11|         -1.11|
|2016-05-1200-C|2016|     5|         1200|   -1|             0|            -1|
| 2016-05-2200-|2016|     5|         2200|    0|            -1|            -1|
| 2016-05-3000-|2016|     5|         3000|    1|            -1|             0|
|2016-06-1200-A|2016|     6|         1200|    0|         -2.11|         -2.11|
|2016-06-1200-B|2016|     6|         1200|    0|         -1.11|         -1.11|
|2016-06-1200-C|2016|     6|         1200|    0|            -1|            -1|
| 2016-06-2200-|2016|     6|         2200|    0|            -1|            -1|
| 2016-06-3000-|2016|     6|         3000|    0|             0|             0|
+--------------+----+------+-------------+-----+--------------+--------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Basically put a map operation on rdd grouped by RowKey2 value, and if there is missing information on period then just use info from last one (if exist).

So i would love to use

```
 df.rdd.partitionBy("RowKey2")\
.mapPartitions(lambda x: filterOutFromPartion(x, periodsList))\
.collect()
```

Which rise

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonPartitioner. Trace:
>   py4j.Py4JException: Constructor
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonPartitioner([class java.lang.String,
>   class java.lang.Long]) does not exist

If I skip partitioning by key, then i get results only for 2 first Rowkeys (each 12 period as expected). Can someone provide me some help there?

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

`partitionBy` signature:

> partitionBy(numPartitions, partitionFunc=)

where first argument is integer and the second (optional) a function. There is no variant which accepts strings. You probably confused it with `Dataframe.repartition`

```
df.repartition(n, "RowKey2")
```

For `partitionBy`:

```
df.rdd.keyBy(lambda x: x.RowKey2).partitionBy(n)
```

It also looks like you make an incorrect assumption that partitionBy works like groupByKey and you get items for a single RowKey. It is not the case: [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/8371915)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should be `keyBy` first.