# Apache Spark Partitioning in map()

Tags: apache-spark

Can anyone explain me this?

> The flipside, however, is that for transformations that cannot be guaranteed to pro‐ duce a known partitioning, the output RDD will not have a partitioner set. For example, if you call map() on a hash-partitioned RDD of key/value pairs, the function passed to map() can in theory change the key of each element, so the result will not have a partitioner. Spark does not analyze your functions to check whether they retain the key. Instead, it provides two other operations, mapValues() and flatMap Values(), which guarantee that each tuple’s key remains the same.

Source [Learning Spark by Matei Zaharia, Patrick Wendell, Andy Konwinski, Holden Karau](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

- Partitioner is a function from a key to partition - [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/9664597)
- Partitioner can be applied on `RDD[(K, V)]` where `K` is the key.
- Once you repartitioned using specific `Partitioner` all pairs with same key are guaranteed to reside on the same partition.

Now, let's consider two examples:

- `map` takes function `(K, V) => U` and returns `RDD[U]` - in other words it transforms a whole `Tuple2`. It might or might not preserve key as is, it might not even return `RDD[(_, _)]` so partitioning is not preserved.
- `mapValues` takes function `(V) => U` and returns `RDD[(K, U)]` - in other words it transforms only values. Key, which determines partition membership, is never touched, so partitioning is preserved.