# Spark even data distribution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioner

I am trying to solve **skewed data** problem in the dataframe. I have introduced a new column based on **bin packing algorithm** which should evenly distribute data among the bins (partitions in my case). My count for the bin is **500,000** rows. 
I have assigned each row a bin number where the row should belongs to. The bin count ranges from **1 to 282**. Let's say the column name is **key**.

Ideally when I do a repartition operation on the dataframe based on the column **key**, it should distribute data evenly among **282 partitions**, each containing records around **500,000**.

```
| key |count |
+-----+------+
|1    |495941|
|2    |499607|
|3    |498896|
|4    |502845|
|5    |498213|
|6    |501325|
|7    |502355|
|8    |501816|
|9    |498829|
|10   |498272|
|11   |499802|
|12   |501580|
|13   |498779|
|14   |498654|
...
...
|282  |491258|
```

But still some partitions contain multiple keys. For example, partition **101** and **115** are combined into **1 partition**, which is unexpected behavior for me.

```
+----+------+
|key |count |
+----+------+
|101 |500014|
|115 |504995|
+----+------+
```

If I write a custom partitioner, then I have to convert my dataframe to rdd and operate on a pair-rdd based on the key column. But Key column can have duplicates initially, and If I groupBy, then multiple records will be combined together and it will break the logic to repartition the data.

It would be great if someone can explain this strange behavior of **reparition** and help me to make it correct.

Comment: Can you share the line of code that did the repartition?, And did you tried with [this variation of `repartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(numPartitions:Int,partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) which receives the number of target partitions?

Comment: _But still some partitions contain multiple keys. (...), which is unexpected behavior for me_ - [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/6910411)