# how is "Exchange hashpartitioning" working in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition, partitioner

I have a dataset which I want to write sorted into parquet files for getting benefit of requesting these files afterwards over Spark including Predicate Pushdown.

Currently I used repartition by column and the number of partitions to move the data to the particular partition. The column is identifying the corresponding partition (beginning from 0 to (fixed) n). The result is that scala/spark is generating an unexpected result and creating less partitions (some of them are empty). Maybe a Hash Collision?

For solving the problem I tried to find out the reason and tried to find workarounds. I found one workaround by transforming the dataframe to rdd and  use partitionBy with HashPartitioner. Surprising for me: I got the expected results. But converting a dataframe to an RDD is not a solution for me, because it takes too much resources.

I have tested this environment on

- SPARK 2.0 on cloudera CDH 5.9.3
- SPARK 2.3.1 on emr-5.17.0

Here is my tests with outputs. Please use Spark-shell to run them

```
    scala> import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
    import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

    scala> val mydataindex = Array(0,1, 2, 3,4)
    mydataindex: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

    scala> val mydata = sc.parallelize(for {
         |  x <- mydataindex
         |  y <- Array(123,456,789)
         | } yield (x, y), 100)
    mydata: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

    scala> val rddMyData = mydata.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(5))
    rddMyData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[1] at partitionBy at <console>:26

    scala> val rddMyDataPartitions =   rddMyData.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
         |                 (index, iterator) => {
         |                    val myList = iterator.toList
         |                    myList.map(x => x + " -> " + index).iterator
         |                 }
         |              }
    rddMyDataPartitions: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at mapPartitionsWithIndex at <console>:26

    scala>
         | // this is expected:

    scala> rddMyDataPartitions.take(100)
    res1: Array[String] = Array((0,123) -> 0, (0,456) -> 0, (0,789) -> 0, (1,123) -> 1, (1,456) -> 1, (1,789) -> 1, (2,123) -> 2, (2,456) -> 2, (2,789) -> 2, (3,456) -> 3, (3,789) -> 3, (3,123) -> 3, (4,789) -> 4, (4,123) -> 4, (4,456) -> 4)

    scala> val dfMyData = mydata.toDF()
    dfMyData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]

    scala> val dfMyDataRepartitioned = dfMyData.repartition(5,col("_1"))
    dfMyDataRepartitioned: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [_1: int, _2: int]

    scala> dfMyDataRepartitioned.explain(false)
    == Physical Plan ==
    Exchange hashpartitioning(_1#3, 5)
    +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1 AS _1#3, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#4]
       +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#2]

    scala> val dfMyDataRepartitionedPartition  = dfMyDataRepartitioned.withColumn("partition_id", spark_partition_id()).groupBy("partition_id").count()
    dfMyDataRepartitionedPartition: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [partition_id: int, count: bigint]

    scala> // this is unexpected, because 1 partition has more indexes

    scala> dfMyDataRepartitionedPartition.show()
    +------------+-----+
    |partition_id|count|
    +------------+-----+
    |           1|    6|
    |           3|    3|
    |           4|    3|
    |           2|    3|
    +------------+-----+
```

I first throught that HashPartitioner is been used in the method of repartitioning a dataframe, but this doesn't seem to be the case, becaue it is working on RDDs.

Could anyone guide me how this "Exchange hashpartitioning" (see explain output above) is working?

2019-01-16 12:20: This is not a duplicate of [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396) because I am interested in the Hashing Algorithm of repartition by column (+ number partitions) on a Integer column. The general HashPartitioner is working as expected as you can see in the source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the case: As I already wrote: I tried with HashPartitioner and I was able to understand how Hashes are calculated there. Here I am asking for the used Hash algorithm in repartion by Column + number of partitions, which has a different result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing unexpected here. As explained in [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work) Spark uses hash(key) modulo number of partitions and non-uniform distribution, especially on small datasets is not unexepected.

Difference between `Dataset` and `RDD` is expected as well, as both use different hashing functions (ditto).

Finally

> The result is that scala/spark is generating an unexpected result and creating less partitions

is not a correct observation. Number of partitions created is exactly the requested

```
scala> dfMyDataRepartitioned.rdd.getNumPartitions
res8: Int = 5
```

but the empty ones won't be visible in the aggregation, because there are no corresponding values.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I am interested in the hash function itself. I am using an Integer field to repartitionBy. A Hashcode from the Itneger is the integer itself. Could you tell me where to find the Implementation of the hash function?

Comment: You were right. It is using Murmur3Hash. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2166