# How to distribute specific data to each cluster node in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I am deploying my program in spark cluster and I need to give each node a specific list of data that I decide on. How can I do this? I created an RDD object out of my data but I don't know how to pass the specific part of data to each node.

Comment: Very vague. What do you want to pass specifically?

Comment: @thebluephantom I need to pass a block of data to each machine but I need to specify which block (and its size and content) goes to which machine

Comment: not sure that is possible unless out of control of spark and you do not know which executors on which node.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible as you have no control which Worker Nodes are allocated, and, N Executors may be on same Worker Node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you can pass a specific list to the node. If your data have unique keys, then you can use hash technique to send same keys on specific partition

Comment: Yes, they have unique keys. But how can I use the hash technique you are talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work