# Why Spark doesn't allow map-side combining with array keys?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I'm using Spark 1.3.1 and I'm curious why Spark doesn't allow using array keys on map-side combining. 
Piece of `combineByKey function`:

```scala
if (keyClass.isArray) {
  if (mapSideCombine) {
    throw new SparkException("Cannot use map-side combining with array keys.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  What do you want to do with the keys? or what do you want to key that you cannot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically for the same reason why [*default partitioner cannot partition array keys*](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/32407bfd2bdbf84d65cacfa7554dae6a2332bc37/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L539).

Scala `Array` is just a wrapper around Java array and its `hashCode` doesn't depend on a content:

```
scala> val x = Array(1, 2, 3)
x: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> val h = x.hashCode
h: Int = 630226932

scala> x(0) = -1

scala> x.hashCode() == h1
res3: Boolean = true
```

It means that two arrays with exact the same content are not equal

```
scala> x
res4: Array[Int] = Array(-1, 2, 3)

scala> val y = Array(-1, 2, 3)
y: Array[Int] = Array(-1, 2, 3)

scala> y == x
res5: Boolean = false
```

As result `Arrays` cannot be used as a meaningful keys. If you're not convinced just check what happens when you use `Array` as key for Scala `Map`:

```
scala> Map(Array(1) -> 1, Array(1) -> 2)
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Array[Int],Int] = Map(Array(1) -> 1, Array(1) -> 2)
```

If you want to use a collection as key you should use an immutable data structure like a `Vector` or a `List`.

```
scala> Map(Array(1).toVector -> 1, Array(1).toVector -> 2)
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Vector[Int],Int] = Map(Vector(1) -> 2)
```

See also:

- [SI-1607](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1607)
- [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/1560062)
- [A list as a key for PySpark's reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31404238/1560062)