# Effect preservesPartitioning RDD true/false gives same result for mapPartitions

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

2nd attempt here, as presented the wrong example initially. From the docs:

> preservesPartitioning indicates whether the input function preserves
>   the partitioner, which should be false unless this is a pair RDD and
>   the input function doesn't modify the keys.

Nice prose, but what does it really mean though?

Here a contrived trivial example, and whether or not I pass true or false to mapPartitions, the partitioning of data per partition remains the same for the new RDD even though I alter the K of K,V. So what is the point? Must be something elementary that I am missing.

```
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
// Some contrived function
def myfunc(iter: Iterator[(String, (Int, String))]) : Iterator[(String, (Int,String))] = {
    iter.map{case(x,y) => ("B"+x+"A", y)} 
}
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 9).map(x => ("RFD"+x+"ABC", (1000, "xc888x"+x))).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(459))
val rdd2 = rdd1.mapPartitions(myfunc,true) // or false
rdd2.collect
```

Output of rdd2 for both true and false with mapPartitionsWithIndex reveals in both cases:

```
res21: Array[String] = Array((BRFD5ABCA,(1000,xc888x5)) -> 22, (BRFD4ABCA,(1000,xc888x4)) -> 66, (BRFD3ABCA,(1000,xc888x3)) -> 110, (BRFD2ABCA,(1000,xc888x2)) -> 154, (BRFD1ABCA,(1000,xc888x1)) -> 198, (BRFD9ABCA,(1000,xc888x9)) -> 305, (BRFD8ABCA,(1000,xc888x8)) -> 349, (BRFD7ABCA,(1000,xc888x7)) -> 393, (BRFD6ABCA,(1000,xc888x6)) -> 437)
```

which is the same partition distribution for rdd1.

So, what is the point of true or false for preservesPartitioning then?

Comment: @user10938362  re-attempt as I posted the wrong example thru all the xmas bustle oddly enough. May be this one makes more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also quite non-intuitive for me. I may quote a statement from from [Apache Spark User List](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/preservesPartitioning-td10019.html) which suits your question:

> This is not what preservesPartitioning does -- actually what it means
>   is that if the RDD has a Partitioner set (which means it's an RDD of
>   key-value pairs and the keys are grouped into a known way, e.g. hashed
>   or range-partitioned), your map function is not changing the partition
>   of keys. This lets the job scheduler know that downstream operations,
>   like joins or reduceByKey, can be optimized assuming that all the data
>   for a given partition is located on the same machine. In both cases
>   though, your function f operates on each partition.

In your example, consider the following code with `preservePartitioing=false`:

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.mapPartitions(myfunc,false) // or false
rdd2.groupByKey().map{case (key,values) => values.size}.toDebugString
```

gives:

```
(459) MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at Spark.scala:44 []
  |   ShuffledRDD[4] at groupByKey at Spark.scala:44 []
  +-(459) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at mapPartitions at Spark.scala:42 []
      |   ShuffledRDD[2] at partitionBy at Spark.scala:41 []
      +-(4) MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at Spark.scala:41 []
         |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at Spark.scala:41 []
```

While with `preservePartitioing=true`:

```
(459) MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at Spark.scala:44 []
  |   MapPartitionsRDD[4] at groupByKey at Spark.scala:44 []
  |   MapPartitionsRDD[3] at mapPartitions at Spark.scala:42 []
  |   ShuffledRDD[2] at partitionBy at Spark.scala:41 []
  +-(4) MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at Spark.scala:41 []
     |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at Spark.scala:41 []
```

So in the first case, `groupByKey` causes an additional shuffle, because spark does not know that the keys reside in the same partition (as the partitioner is lost), in the second case, `groupByKey` is translated to a simple `mapPartitions` because spark knows that the first `mapPartitions` did not change the partitioning, i.e. that the keys are still in the same partition.

Comment: Subtle to say the least. But I am glad of the quote: This is also quite non-intuitive for me.

Comment: @thebluephantom you may also study this related question  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288483/why-filter-does-not-preserve-partitioning