# Why does RDD.map fail with "Cannot use map-side combining with array keys for the code" while RDD.flatMap does not?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running the below code and getting error message as : **Cannot use map-side combining with array keys for the code**

```
val lines = sc.textFile("../book.txt")    
val line = lines.Map(x => (x.split(" ")))    
val tense = line.map(x => (x,1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y)    
tense.foreach(println)
```

But when I use flatMap instead of map in line 2 it works perfectly. Why?

Comment: Because `lines.map(x => (x.split(" ")))` results in a `RDD[Array[String]]` (i.e. each line in the text file becomes an array of split words).  Replacing `map` with `flatMap` would flatten the RDD into `RDD[String]` of split words across all lines.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698428/why-spark-doesnt-allow-map-side-combining-with-array-keys - to understand why Spark can't use `reduceByKey` if the key has type `Array`. In this case, if you're trying to count words, what you actually need is `flatMap` (as pointed out in previous comment) which would create an RDD with key of type `String`.